# What exactly is dev/nvme01p1 and why does it cause my Kubuntu install to think there are no bootable disks?

Tags: boot, partitioning, kubuntu, nvme

New to Linux and Kubuntu.
I am installing Kubuntu 22.04 on a 2017 Acer Swift 3. I originally managed to install it only on a drive called "dev/nvme01p1" also labeled Intel Mem-something, since the installation didn't let me delete windows.
I cleared the windows partition from de Disk Utility in Kubuntu, andthen reinstalled Kubuntu on "dev/sda", where I wanted it to begin with.
I rebooted on /sda and cleared the /nvme partition (unmounted, repathed the /sda fat32 to /boot/efi), and then the OS got incredibly confused and I had to manually turn it off. Then upon rebooting the computer said it had no bootable disks.
I went to install Kubuntu again and the /sda does have Kubuntu in it, and /nvme is still free space. Currently reinstalling on /sda to see if that helps but I've clearly done something incredibly stupid and I don't know what it was.
Reason I wanted to install on /sda is that /nvme only has 14gb, while /sda has 1tb.
Can someone explain to me what I did wrong and how to fix it please? Will update when new installation is done. Thanks!

UPDATE1: Reinstalled to /sda and it seems to start up normally (though slow) after reboot. I noticed when starting from nvme it was starting faster but I don't mind the wait (unless there's a way to start it up faster). Will install updates and see what happens.

UPDATE2: Device seems to be working fine now. Thank you all for your kind responses. The SSD is still empty, so I wonder of there's a way to use them both with the same OS... Do I have to partition it a specific way to allow the computer to use it? Thanks again.

Comment: `/dev/nvme0n1` is your NVMe SSD and `/dev/sda` is your HDD. If you were not careful while formatting your '/dev/sda' partitions, (`/dev/sda` is the whole disk. you cant format this. `/dev/sda1` is the partition.) you could've deleted your Kubuntu installation completely. If you need fast boot times, i recommend installing on your NVMe SSD.

Comment: @Emre, yes you can format a whole disk. A newly formatted disk contains no partitions or file systems.

Answer (score 1):

`/dev` is for [device files](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file).

Anything starting with `/dev/nvme` is a hard drive identified as an NVMe SSD. However, most other hard drives (SCSI disks, SATA disks, and USB disks) are identified as `/dev/sdX`, where `X` is a letter.

To install Ubuntu, please follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop).  If you encounter issues, you can reference the tutorial when asking.

After installation, you may need to instruct your motherboard to boot from the disk where you installed Ubuntu. If you need help with setting up boot priority, you should consult the documentation or support for your motherboard since this can vary between motherboard models, and is not controlled by Ubuntu or any other operating system.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, this was helpful.